# How to include bars in in a QChart with QValueAxis?

Tags: c++, qt, qchart

I need a combined chart showing multiple lineseries (given by x,y values) and bars (given by x_start,x_end and y values; somewhat like a histogram) in QtCharts.

Unfortunately it is not possible to assign a `QValueAxis` to a `QBarseries`, so I can't just include a number of bar series. I tried using `QCandlestickSeries`, but it seems like even though the timestamp is supposed to be a `qreal` type, candlesticks are only put at integer values (Bug?).

I was also thinking about making my own `MyBarSeries` class inheriting from `QAbstractSeries`, but that seems complicated. Another alternative would be to combine a `QValueAxis` and `QBarCategoryAxis` somehow, but I need zooming and panning in the chart which makes this difficult aswell.

I would highly appreciate it if anyone had an idea on how to do this, or could show me in the rigt direction.